# Find in nested document to dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection of documents structured as follows:

```
[{
 "id_":abc,
 "username":"John",
 "data":{
   "phone_number":"+123",
   "address":"street 1"
  }
},
{
 "id_":def,
 "username":"Marie",
 "data":{
    "phone_number":"+456",
    "address":"street 2"
  }
}]
```

I would like to get all the phone numbers in a pandas dataframe. At the moment, I am doing the following:

```
resp=collection.find({},{'data.phone_number':1,'_id':0})
df=pd.DataFrame(list(map(lambda x: x['data'],list(resp))))
```

Is there a more natural way to perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If phone numbers are unique you can use [distinct](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct)

```
numbers = collection.distinct('data.phone_number')
df=pd.DataFrame(numbers, columns = ['phone_number'])
```

If they are not unique there's no real better way, you use achieve similar results with an aggregation pipeline but It won't really improve performance.